# Site that provides up to date list of programming languages/frameworks to open source repositories using it?

Tags: uses-of-open-data, programming

When you are learning how to program in a certain language or with a particular framework, it is very useful to have an actual real-world example of that project being used somewhere in the open source community.

Has anyone stumbled across a particular updated website or online resource that provides OSS source code links (like github, sourceforge, etc) to programming languages / frameworks?

This would be especially useful for software engineering professionals who need to learn a new language/framework and want to skip the "Hello World" and get right to something useful.

Comment: https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=language:OCaml&sort=stars&order=desc ?

Comment: [On Wikidata](https://query.wikidata.org/#select%20distinct%20%3Frepository%20%7B%0Avalues%20%28%3Fname%29%20%7B%28%22OCaml%22%40en%29%7D%0A%20%20%3Fproject%20wdt%3AP277%20%5B%20wdt%3AP31%2Fwdt%3AP279%2a%20wd%3AQ9143%20%3B%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3Fname%20%5D%20%3B%20wdt%3AP1324%20%3Frepository%20.%0A%7D)

Comment: oooo @StanislavKralin good idea!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Open Hub](https://www.openhub.net/) has something almost exactly like this, although I don't think there are specific pointers that say "we use this code, like this, here".

[Firefox's profile](https://www.openhub.net/p/firefox) profile shows [image: Screenshot of Firefox's Profile on Open Hub] some of the data they provide for open source projects.

Github's annual [State of the Octoverse](https://octoverse.github.com/projects.html) provides some level of details about what you are asking to.